# Is it possible to create an alert with more than 2 buttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I need to create an alert with 3 buttons, but it looks like SwiftUI only gives us two options right now: one button or two buttons. I know that with UIKit, 3 buttons are achievable, but I can't seem to find a workaround in the latest version of SwiftUI to do this. Below is my code where I'm using only a primary and secondary button.

```
Button(action: {
    self.showAlert = true
}){
    Text("press me")
}
.alert(isPresented: self.$showAlert){
     Alert(title: Text("select option"), message: Text("pls help"), primaryButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("yes"), action: {
         print("yes clicked")
         }), secondaryButton: Alert.Button.cancel(Text("no"), action: {
         print("no clicked")
     })
     )
}
```

Comment: Not **yet**. And you can't design a custom `View` for that **yet**. But I think you can use a custom `UIView` for that.

Comment: The answer is both yes and no. You can't create an alert with more than 3 buttons but you can create an actionsheet which is pretty much the same thing.

Comment: You could also write your own View that would look like an Alert with 3 buttons.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is now possible on iOS 15/macOS 12 with a new version of the alert modifier: [`alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:)-9h5um).

It works a bit differently because the `Alert` struct isn't used anymore; you use regular SwiftUI `Button`s instead. Add a `ButtonRole` to indicate which buttons perform the "cancel" action or "destructive" actions. Add the `.keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)` modifier to a button to indicate it performs the principal action.

For example:

```swift
MyView()
    .alert("Test", isPresented: $presentingAlert) {
        Button("one", action: {})
        Button("two", action: {}).keyboardShortcut(.defaultAction)
        Button("three", role: .destructive, action: {})
        Button("four", role: .cancel, action: {})
    }
```

Creates the following alert:

[image: Alert]

Comment: How to add alert message?

Comment: Use [`alert(_:isPresented:presenting:actions:message:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/alert(_:ispresented:presenting:actions:message:)-8584l) instead.

Comment: how can add title/heading?

Comment: The first parameter in the iOS 15+ alert modifiers I mention is for the title.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be compatible with previous versions of iOS 15, consider to use actionSheet like this:

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showActionSheet) {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Title"), message: Text("Choose one of this three:"), buttons: [
        .default(Text("First")) { },
        .default(Text("Second")) { },
        .default(Text("Third")) { },
        .cancel()
    ])
}
```

Comment: looks a little unconventional but that's a good option as corner case solution. thanks :)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work on iPad :(

Answer (score 4):

.actionSheet, .sheet, and .popover are options to provide custom alerts. Consider this sample:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showModal = false
    @State private var cnt = 0
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Counter is \(cnt)")
            Button("Show alert") {
                self.showModal = true
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showModal,
               onDismiss: {
                print(self.showModal)}) {
                    CustomAlert(message: "This is Modal view",
                              titlesAndActions: [("OK", {}),
                                                 ("Increase", { self.cnt += 1 }),
                                                 ("Cancel", nil)])
        }
    }
}

struct CustomAlert: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentation
    let message: String
    let titlesAndActions: [(title: String, action: (() -> Void)?)] // = [.default(Text("OK"))]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(message)
            Divider().padding([.leading, .trailing], 40)
            HStack {
                ForEach(titlesAndActions.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    Button(self.titlesAndActions[i].title) {
                        (self.titlesAndActions[i].action ?? {})()
                        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

example below requires iOS 14.0 and available for both iPad and iPhone.
i also beleive this code will require minimum modifications to support iOS 13.0 as well.
(xcode project with usage example is available [here](https://github.com/sugarbaron/swiftui-alert))

```
import SwiftUI

public extension View {
    
    func alert(if condition: Binding<Bool>,
               title: String = "",
               text: String = "",
               buttons: [Alert.Option] = [.cancel("OK")]) -> some View {
        let alert: AlertView = .init(condition, title, text, buttons)
        return overlay(condition.wrappedValue ? alert : nil)
    }
    
}

private struct AlertView : View {
    
    @Binding var active: Bool
    private let title: String
    private let text: String
    private let buttons: [Alert.Option]
    private let cancel: Alert.Option?
    
    init(_ active: Binding<Bool>, _ title: String, _ text: String, _ buttons: [Alert.Option]) {
        self._active = active
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
        self.buttons = buttons.filter { $0.role != .cancel }
        self.cancel = buttons.first { $0.role == .cancel } ?? (buttons.isEmpty ? .cancel("OK") : nil)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            if title.count > 0 { Text(title).fontWeight(.semibold).padding([.top, .bottom], 5) }
            if text.count > 0 { Text(text).fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true) }
            ForEach(buttons, id: \.label) { Divider(); button(for: $0) }
            if let cancel { Divider(); button(for: cancel) }
        }.padding()
         .frame(maxWidth: width)
         .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
         .cornerRadius(20)
         .shadow(color: Color(.black), radius: 5)
         .screenCover()
         .onTapGesture { if cancellable { active = false } }
    }
    
    private func button(for option: Alert.Option) -> some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(option.label)
                .foregroundColor(option.role == .destructive ? Color(.red) : Color(.link))
                .fontWeight(option.role == .cancel ? .semibold : .regular)
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 5)
            Spacer()
        }.background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
         .onTapGesture { if option.role != .cancel { option.action() }; active = false }
    }
    
    private var width: CGFloat { min((UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8), 500) }
    
    private var cancellable: Bool { cancel != nil }
    
}

extension Alert {
    
    public final class Option {
        
        public let label: String
        public let role: Role
        public let action: () -> Void
        
        public init(_ label: String, role: Role = .regular, action: @escaping () -> Void = { }) {
            self.label = label
            self.role = role
            self.action = action
        }
        
        public static func cancel(_ label: String) -> Option { .init(label, role: .cancel) }
        
    }
    
}

public extension SwiftUI.Alert.Option { enum Role { case regular; case cancel; case destructive } }

public extension View {
    
    func screenCover(_ color: Color = .init(UIColor.systemBackground), opacity: Double = 0.5) -> some View {
        color.opacity(opacity)
             .ignoresSafeArea()
             .overlay(self)
    }
    
}
```